# What is the difference between keras.layers.core and keras.layers

Tags: deep-learning, keras

We can import a Dense layer from:
**1.**`from keras.layers import Dense`
**2.** `from keras.layers.core import Dense`

Similarly for Conv2D:
**1.**`from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D`
**2.**`from keras.layers import Conv2D`

So what is the difference between the above lines.If they are the same why the syntax is different?

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: So why are there 2 methods?

Comment: Backwards compatibility - at some point the API changed, but they wanted to keep the compatibility